# KnockoutJS: Enable/disable a checkbox when value of a text (number) input is > 0

Tags: knockout.js

I'd like to ask a user how many children he/she has, and when he/she has more than 0, a checkbox "single parent?" should be enabled, otherwise disabled.

I'm very new to KnockoutJS and made my through the tutorials on the page, but I seem to fail at this very basic need. I made a jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jmuheim/26x9v/

One important thing: when an existing user edits his info, the number of children is read from the database, so the `<input value="xxx" />` should be respected by KnockoutJS.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just used the enable if numberOfChildren is greater than 0

```
<div>
  number of children:
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: numberOfChildren"/>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: singleParent, enable: numberOfChildren() > 0" />
  single parent?
</div>
```

Here the json is coming from the server/db and then assigned to the relevant observables which are then bound to the page

```
$(function() {
    var modelFromServer = {
        numberOfChildren: 3,
        singleParent: false
    };

    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(modelFromServer));
});

var ViewModel = function (model) {
    self.numberOfChildren = ko.observable(model.numberOfChildren)
    self.singleParent = ko.observable(model.singleParent)
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j7srW/3/

Comment: Knockout **does not need** jQuery.

Comment: Yeah sorry. I was wrong. You need it if you are going to perform ajax requests

Comment: This looks quite nice already. But isn't there an easy way to use the value of the input as `numberOfChildren`? And do I really need a `modelFromServer`?

Comment: The normal thing to do with knockout is to have a model on the server of a user. This would then be serialized to json and passed into your constructor. Knockout works best if you just set your observable value and then bind it to the view. Of course there are other ways of doing this but this is best practice. If you didn't want to serialise to json you could just manually create the json in javascript and just set each individual value. The problem with that is if you add additional fields to user then these would also need to be added in this json javascript code.